# Trying to replace NA with 1

Tags: r

I have variable a in a dataset b

```
NA
NA
NA
53
53
NA
```

I want the output as

```
1
1
1 
53
53
1
```

I tried

```
b$a1[i1] <- ifelse(b$a[i1]=="NA", 1,b$a[i1])
```

But it is not getting replace. Format of a is list

Comment: Use `is.na()` function for checking whether the value is NA or not

Comment: I tried the above is.na(). It showing false for values but not showing true for NA

Comment: Can you please include the output of `str(b)`?

Answer (score 3):

The answer you are looking for is

```
b$a[is.na(b$a)] <- 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `replace`

```
 with(b, replace(a, is.na(a), 1))
```